# Should you default HMENU to nullptr or 0?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

It is not clear to me. Which is correct?

- `HMENU hMenu = 0;`
- `HMENU hMenu = nullptr;`

?

Comment: Why not let the compiler figure it out for you: `HMENU hMenu {};`

Comment: @IInspectable Can I use that with any variable (within reason)?

Comment: Should be valid for any primitive type. The exact rules are spelled out here: [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization). The rules are much more involved than you'd expect. In a nutshell, `T t{};` is the same as `T t = T();`, except when it isn't. I don't know when that is the case.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks. That worked, but later on in the same function I have again `if (hMenu != 0)`. In this context I can't use `{}` can I. Is `if(hMenu)` sufficient?

Comment: I'd probably go with `if(hMenu)`. C++ can implicitly convert pointers to `bool`, where a null pointer evaluates to `false` and any non-null pointer to `true`. Should you ever replace `hMenu` with a resource wrapper (like the [WIL](https://github.com/microsoft/wil)'s RAII types) the code continues to be correct. This is particularly interesting with types that have more than one invalid value (like a `HANDLE`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows API came before `nullptr`. The reason for the introduction of `nullptr` is that the compiler sometimes gets confused between the "zero integer" and "null pointer". This is usually a problem in function overload. The programmer might also get confused between "zero integer" and "null pointer". Using `nullptr` is recommended, otherwise `nullptr`, `NULL`, and `0` are the same thing.

To make things more confusing, some Windows's null handles are non-zero values. For example the return value for `CreateFile` is `INVALID_FILE_HANDLE` when function fails. In this case you must write `if(hfile != INVALID_FILE_HANDLE){success...}`

The argument being made, is that if you have a habit of writing `if(handle)`, instead of `if(handle != specific_null_handle)`, you end up writing the wrong code when `specific_null_handle` is not zero. Otherwise `if(handle)` is the same code as `if(handle != nullptr)` as far as the compiler is concerned.

To be consistent with Windows API, you should write `NULL`, or swap `NULL` with `nullptr`.

Answer (score 4):

To be pedantic, you should use neither, but instead `HMENU hMenu = NULL;`.

- [`nullptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) is a C++'ism, only standardized in C++11, while Win32 is a C API predating that.
- `HMENU` is an opaque pointer, like other Win32 handles, so [`NULL`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL) is more appropriate than `0`.

That said, using either of `NULL`, `0` or `nullptr` in that statement will compile to the same machine code in the end, and work the same.

Comment: I will say this is not correct. The code in question doesn't call the Windows API. It initializes a variable in C++ code. The [nullptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) keyword denotes the null pointer literal, providing implicit conversions to the null pointer value of any pointer type. It is the standard C++ way to initialize a variable of pointer type with the null pointer value.

Comment: @IInspectable On the other hand [when in Rome...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_in_Rome,_do_as_the_Romans_do) though I agree it's a matter of stylistic choice and personal preference in the end. My take is that the Win32 API was defined and worked for a couple of decades before `nullptr` existed, and still does to the day. Writing `nullptr` when compiling new code as C++ vs. `NULL` when compiling the same code as plain C doesn't change the fact that the API, documentation and existing code are all C legacy that uses `NULL` throughout, so I find it more consistent to do the same.

Comment: The app in question is MFC. But I have used nullptr a lot. But that makes sense when the variable is an actual pointer. But handles .... Also, Visual Studio Assist flags me using 0 and wants me to use nullptr. My app is a mixture anyway. Some CStringArray, some vector etc.. I use different things as I learn new ways.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle There is no wrong choice there, as long as you keep your own code consistent. MFC itself uses `NULL` in preference to `nullptr` in its sources, documentation and official samples, though that's likely due to old age and thinness of its Win32 wrappers, rather than a deep design/style decision.

Comment: MFC uses `NULL`, because that's all we had in 1992. With MFC being a C++ library, the distinction between `NULL` and `nullptr` starts to matter. Using `nullptr` should be preferred with MFC (or any C++ code) to prevent overload resolution ambiguities.

Comment: Incidentally, for child windows HMENU is always an integer cast to type HMENU never a handle. (It's the 16 bit control id you get back in WM_COMMAND and related stuff).